# I've got this code, but I don't know how to save what the user inputs as their Username

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's the code (I have more code above it, and I have imported Tkinter)

```
username = Tk()
username.title ("Usernames")
username.geometry("280x70")
Label(username, text='Player One').grid(row=0)
Label(username, text='Player Two').grid(row=3)
e1 = Entry(username)
e2 = Entry(username)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Nothing happened out of the ordinary, I just don't know how to save/print what the user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a code that will print the text from the entry to the console.  i have put a comment for you to understand too.

```py
from tkinter import *

# Create a window
root = Tk()
root.title("Usernames")
root.geometry("280x70")

# Create a label widget
player_one = Label(root, text="Player One")
player_two = Label(root, text="Player Two")

# Create an entry widget
e1 = Entry(root)
e2 = Entry(root)




# Place the label and entry widgets in the window
player_one.grid(row=0, column=0)
player_two.grid(row=1, column=0)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

# print the contents of the entry widgets
def callback():
    print(e1.get())
    print(e2.get())
    root.destroy()

# Create a button widget
button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=callback)

# Place the button widget in the window
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Run the main loop

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, my code was flawed to begin with!

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know how to save what the user inputs as their Username.

Avoid wildcard `import *`. Use this `import tkinter as tk` then use prefix `tk.` for widgets.

The problem can be fixed.

- Add namespace `configparser`
- Use parser.get to load playe1 and player2
- Create `save_teams` function to save save.

Run the script. It will load player1 and player2 on Entry widgets.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import configparser

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('RougeDemon.ini')
  
_player1= parser.get('Teams', 'player1')
_player2= parser.get('Teams', 'player2')
  
username = tk.Tk()
username.title ("Usernames")
username.geometry("280x70")

def save_teams() -> str:
    entry_player_one = e1.get()
    entry_player_two = e2.get()
    
    if not parser.has_section("Teams"):
        parser.add_section('Teams')
    parser.set('Teams', 'player1', e1.get())
    parser.set('Teams', 'player2', e2.get())

    with open("RougeDemon.ini", "w") as config:
        parser.write(config)    
   
tk.Label(username, text='Player One').grid(row=0)
tk.Label(username, text='Player Two').grid(row=3)
 
e1 = tk.Entry(username)
e1.insert(0, _player1)

e2 = tk.Entry(username)
e2.insert(0, _player2)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=3, column=1)

tk.Button(username, text='Click', command=save_teams).grid()
 
username.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]